# Check for process and kill if running

Tags: shell, process, ps

I am trying to find if a process is running or not, and if it is runing then I want to call a script or print something. I tried with the below few ways, but it gives me syntax error or command not found error.

```
APP_ID = ps -eaf | grep -i `whoami` | grep -i <process_name> | grep -i java | awk '{print$2}'

if[''!= '${APP_ID}'] then
    echo "Stopping instance $APP_ID"
```

I get the result as below:

```
test.sh: line 15: APP_ID: command not found
test.sh: line 17: if[!= ${APP_ID}]: command not found
Stopping instance
```

What is wrong in the above script? And if it has some errors, then why does it print the `echo` in the `if` condition?

Also the below script fails saying `test.sh: line 3: [ps: command not found`

```
if [ps -eaf | grep -i `whoami` | grep -i <process_name> | grep -i java]; then
    echo 'stop'
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

### Your syntax has many problems:

- remove spaces around "=" when setting a variable

  wrong:

  ```
  APP_ID = value
  ```

  right:

  ```
  APP_ID=value
  ```
- to run a program and put its output into a variable, you need `$(...)` (preferred in bash, not available in sh) or backticks `` `command` `` (supported in bash and sh). (and remember that when assigning a variable, quotes are not needed, but in other cases they are important: `command "$(command)"`)

  wrong:

  ```
  APP_ID=command
  ```

  right:

  ```
  APP_ID=$(command)
  ```
- add spaces around everything when using "[", and you need a semicolon or newline after the "]". This is because "[" is a bash builtin command, and the non-builtin one is also known as "test" (see `man test`), which just like other commands, takes its arguments separated by space:

  wrong:

  ```
  if[x!= y] then echo hello world fi
  ```

  right:

  ```
  if [ x != y ]; then echo hello world; fi
  ```
- use double quotes, not single quotes when you want to expand a variable

  wrong:

  ```
  if [ '' != '${APP_ID}' ]; then
  ```

  right:

  ```
  if [ '' != "${APP_ID}" ]; then
  ```
- Also for the above example, you can use -n (non-empty) instead of comparing to empty string

  ```
  if [ -n "${APP_ID}" ]; then
  ```
- And for the ps example, you don't need grep and awk:

  ```
  APP_ID=$(ps -C whoami --no-header --format 'pid')
  ```

### And so here is the fixed up script:

```
APP_ID=$(ps -C whoami --no-header --format 'pid')

if [ -n "${APP_ID}" ]; then
    echo "Stopping instance $APP_ID"
fi
```

Comment: `[` is a built in of bash. But behaves as if it is a separate command. On some shells it is. You can find `[` in `/usr/bin/[`, and it has a man page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do we need to provide the pid in the above script ? I just have the process name which I want to stop. I am very new to scripting and trying to learn hence please bear with me for the stupid questions.

Comment: @user179309 in the above script, it looks by name, just like you did with `whoami`, and the APP_ID will be a single or multi-line string including all the process ids (depending on how many processes are found).

Comment: @richard thanks, I guess you're right that I implied it's the same when it's not, so I fixed that.

Answer (score 5):

This is easiest done with `pgrep` and `pkill`:

```
if pgrep process_name 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "Terminating process_name"
  pkill process_name
fi
```

As user @OrangeDog points out in the comments, there is the theoretical possibility of this shell code failing to terminate the process `process_name` *if the process spawns inbetween the call to `pgrep` and `pkill`*.  In this case, `pgrep` would not detect the process and `pkill` would never execute.  How much of a problem this is, I don't know. If the process spawns just *after* the statement, what can you do?

Just do

```
echo "terminating process_name (if it is running)"
pkill process_name
```

to be rid of the pesky race condition in any case.

Comment: Why bother checking beforehand?

Comment: @OrangeDog Because in script in the question, the OP clearly tries to do the same.

Comment: This has a race condition. The process you kill may not be the same one that you grepped for.

Comment: @OrangeDog There is technically a race condition in there in terms of what PIDs gets signalled, true. But the signal with be delivered to the instances of `process_name` running while `pkill` is executing none the less. It would have been worse if I had taken the PIDs from `pgrep` and fed them to `kill`, which might have left some recently spawned instance of `process_name` running. This will not be the case here.

Comment: @OrangeDog The "worst" thing that could happen is that `process_name` terminates before we get to `pkill`.

Comment: No the worst thing that happens is you kill the replacement process for the one you were supposed to be killing.

Comment: @OrangeDog If I wanted to kill a *specific* process, I would not use `pkill`, I would keep track of the PID of that process and use `kill $somepid`. In this case, I find it hard to come up with even an academic situation where this race condition would cause undesired results. Oh, there is one! If `process_name` spawns inbetween the calls, without existing before. Sigh, I'll add a note..

Comment: @OrangeDog It's still just academic. If you run `pkill process_name` and the process spawns just afterwards, what have you gained?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why but the above script was not giving any syntax issues but was not giving the process id also though the process was running.

I finally changed it as below and it works -

```
APP_ID=$(ps -ef | grep <app_name> | grep java | awk '{print $2}')

echo "Instance $APP_ID"
if [ -n "${APP_ID}" ]; then
    echo "Stopping instance $APP_ID"
fi
```

Thanks once again for the explanation and pointers.

@Peter I will check again the script you posted on why it is not working for me.

Comment: Don't do this `ps … | grep …` stuff, it's unreliable: sooner or later you'll end up killing an unrealted process with a resembling name. Use `pgrep` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The command above will also catch the grep it self, so the command, in case of java process, should be

```
APP_ID=$(ps -ef | grep <app_name> | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

echo "Instance $APP_ID"
if [ -n "${APP_ID}" ]; then
    echo "Stopping instance $APP_ID"
    kill $APP_ID   (or kill -9 $APP_ID)
fi
```

hope this helps.